# TensorFlow, Multi-Phase Training

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I want to have a multi-layer ConvNet such that at every phase I only train one layer of it. My code sketch looks like the following:

```
def MyConvNet(training_phase, input):

    # conv1 structure
    ...
    # conv2 structure
    ...
    # conv3 structure
    ...

    if(training_phase == 1):
       return conv1_out
    if(training_phase == 2):
       return conv2_out
    if(training_phase == 3):
       return conv3_out
```

The problem is that this code is not working and I get the following error:

```
 ValueError: None values not supported.
```

How can I implement such function which implements a multi-layer ConvNet with the ability to get the output of each layer in different training phases, in TensorFlow?

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want? How would you even train one layer at a time, conceptually?

Comment: @Neal suppose that its a regression problem and each layer output has the same dimension as final output.

Comment: Can you provide more code?

Comment: Guess into the blue: Have the session within the same level as the calls to `MyConvNet` or use Save-Points.